# i3wm urxvt wrapping issue when using hot key to launch. no issue when run from dmenu

Tags: terminal, urxvt, fish, i3-window-manager

Sorry for the long title. Wanted it be a little specific. I have an issue with my urxvt (rxvt-unicode) terminal emulator that's using a themed fish shell. The problem is that when I launch urxvt with mod+enter the line wrapping messes up causing the datetime part to wrap onto the next line. Furthermore, when i start to type each letter is printed consequently on the next line. see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83grW.png).

However, the issue is fixed if i launch the urxvt terminal from the dmenu.
image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzAkN.png).

Comment: Fish version? What does `stty -a` report in both cases? What does `env | grep LINES` and `env | grep COLUMNS` output?

Comment: nvm, I found what the issue was. Thanks anyways :))

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the hassle, I found what the issue was in this [doc](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/locale#My_terminal_does_not_support_UTF-8).
Specifically this part

> **Gnome-terminal or rxvt-unicode**
>
> You need to launch these applications from a UTF-8 locale or they will
> drop UTF-8 support. Enable the en_US.UTF-8 locale (or your local UTF-8
> alternative) per the instructions above and set it as the default
> locale, then reboot.